# How to replace %20 with a hyphen from routing config in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I need guidance removing the Modulos signs from my url. I want my routing exactly like below.

> stackoverflow.com/questions/15881575/get-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc

My routing returns something

> stackoverflow.com/questions/15881575/get%20the%20selected%20value%20of%20a%20dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc.

Notice the %20 returned. Please how do I get a hyphen instead?

Below is my routing config.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          name: null,
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
          defaults: new
          {
              controller = "Home",
              action = "Index",
              title=UrlParameter.Optional,
              id = UrlParameter.Optional
          }
          );
```

Title is a string parameter from my action method. I thought of doing like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: null,
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
          defaults: new
          {
              controller = "Home",
              action = "Index",
              title=UrlParameter.Optional.ToString().Replace(' ','-'),
              id = UrlParameter.Optional
          }
          );
```

However it fails. I alternatively tried

```
 title=UrlParameter.Optional.ToString().Replace("%20","-"),
```

It fails as well. I am new to this and trying to get it better. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried decoding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%20` is the URL-encoded version of a space.  You cannot solve this problem using the routing definitions, you must modify your code which generates the link in the first place, so that it strips out the spaces.

For example, if you are currently generating your link using:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { 
    id = item.Id, 
    title = item.Title 
})
```

You would change it to

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new {
    id = item.Id,
    title = item.Title.Replace(" ", "-")
})
```

Note that you'll probably need to deal with other characters besides space, so you are probably better off using:

```
title = Regex.Replace(item.Title, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
```

Comment: Thank you sir. The first one works. However the RegEx is given an error for the unclose quotation in razor/html.

Comment: Yah i noticed the mistake sir. However the reg is not working. It Remove the first letter from the string instead. :)

Comment: Another typo corrected.  It was only a simple regex intended to illustrate that you may need to deal with more than spaces in this problem.

Comment: thank you.  It works perfect. Also i am replacing with "-" not "" like you have written . Thank you once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to turn this into a POST. Then you don't write any code that converts anything to anything else.